# fetch info of bars by ccxt lib in python return timestamp in time zone incorrect

Tags: python, fetch, ccxt, ohlcv

i fetch_ohlcv and return the data, and in data contains timestamp, and I don't understand why timestamp is in the 0th timezone, while I'm in the 7th timezone

i use testnet environment

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({
    "apiKey": config.BINANCE_API_KEY,
    "secret": config.BINANCE_SECRET_KEY,
    'options': { 'adjustForTimeDifference': True }
})
exchange.set_sandbox_mode(True)  

bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(SYMBOL, timeframe=TIME_FRAME, limit=LIMIT)

df = pd.DataFrame(bars[:-1], columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there some reason you expect the times to be in a different zone than what you're getting?  Since a server can be accessed from anywhere, it's quite common for it to represent times in GMT and leave it to the caller to convert to their local time zone...something that's easy to do. - Just go with it.  So long as you know how to interpret the times, and they're consistent, there shouldn't be a problem.